# Ghostscript (PDF to JPG convert) set only height

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript

I tried today convert pdf to jpg with ghostscript. I want as result jpg image with 500 pixels height. So width depends on orginal pdf page width. I call script from terminal with:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dDEVICEHEIGHT=500 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=/home/user/output/%d.jpg /home/user/input.pdf -c quit
```

but, i get jpg image with height of 842 pixels. Size of input pdf page: 6.73 × 9.49 inch

How can I set only height for image? Thanks

Comment: if you do not insist on ghostcript (gs), the easier method would be to convert pdf->ps (pdf2ps) and then to jpg (ps2jpg). Maybe there is direct converter pdf->jpg ...

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution that works finally?

Answer (score 2):

The PDF interpreter will call for a page size based on the content of the PDF. Unless you set -dFIXEDMEDIA then it will override (mostly) anything you set on the command line. You probably also want to look at the PDFFitPage option. See /gs/doc/use.html

Comment: Neither option does the trick. -dFIXEDMEDIA crops the image. -FitPage scales to fit both, width and height.

Comment: You need to use **both** FIXEDMEDIA and FitPage. FitPage scales both dimensions equally, and scales them so that the minimum required scaling is applied. If you want something else then you will have to modify the logic.